# NSDateFormatter returning wrong year

Tags: objective-c

I am using a pretty basic method to turn dates into strings.

```
+(NSString*)stringForDate:(NSDate*)date {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ddMMYYYY"];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
    return [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
```

But some of them are coming back with the wrong years. Here's a sample of the log.

```
2014-05-25 00:26:46.050 App Name[1868:60b] 2013-12-26 16:00:00 +0000
2014-05-25 00:26:46.051 App Name[1868:60b] 27122013
2014-05-25 00:26:46.051 App Name[1868:60b] 2013-12-27 16:00:00 +0000
2014-05-25 00:26:46.051 App Name[1868:60b] 28122013
2014-05-25 00:26:46.051 App Name[1868:60b] 2013-12-28 16:00:00 +0000
2014-05-25 00:26:46.052 App Name[1868:60b] 29122014
2014-05-25 00:26:46.052 App Name[1868:60b] 2013-12-29 16:00:00 +0000
2014-05-25 00:26:46.054 App Name[1868:60b] 30122014
```

Ignore the fact that the days appear to be a day later - that's expected, due to time zone. However, all the dates being fed in are 2013, but some of the strings are coming back with 2014.

Any help appreciated - it's doing my head in!

Comment: A silly mistake, but easy to make! More importantly, you constructed your test code and your question extremely well, making the diagnosis easy. Well done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing is that `YYYY` and `yyyy` are two quite different things. You are using `YYYY`, which, as the [docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) tell you, is not necessarily the same as the calendar year.

Comment: @JamesWhite You're [not the first person](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/01/ask-ars-why-will-apples-do-not-disturb-bug-fix-itself-next-week/) to have trouble with this :)

Comment: @JesseRusak That was hilarious! Didn't know about it.

Comment: Ha! I'll take solace from that!