# Why Xcode & Simulator give me different dates?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, dateformatter

I have this simple code (Xcode iOS app)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                let dateToday = Date()
                let dateOneYearAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: dateToday) ?? dateToday
                print("dateToday: \(dateToday) - dateOneYearAgo: \(dateOneYearAgo)")
                
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
                
                let dateTodayString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateToday)
                let dateOneYearAgoString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateOneYearAgo)
                print("dateTodayString: \(dateTodayString) - dateOneYearAgoString: \(dateOneYearAgoString)")
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Test").font(.largeTitle)
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

If I run it in Simulator it prints out

dateToday: 2022-12-29 17:24:37 +0000 - dateOneYearAgo: 2021-12-29 17:24:37 +0000
dateTodayString: 2022-12-29 - dateOneYearAgoString: 2022-12-29

If I run in Swift Playgrounds just the action closure like:

```
import Foundation

let dateToday = Date()
let dateOneYearAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: dateToday) ?? dateToday
print("dateToday: \(dateToday) - dateOneYearAgo: \(dateOneYearAgo)")

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateToday)
let dateOneYearAgoString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateOneYearAgo)
print("dateToday: \(dateString) - dateOneYearAgo: \(dateOneYearAgoString)")
```

it gives me:

dateToday: 2022-12-29 17:27:32 +0000 - dateOneYearAgo: 2021-12-29 17:27:32 +0000
dateTodayString: 2022-12-29 - dateOneYearAgoString: 2021-12-29

I would expect that dateOneYearAgoString is always 2021-12-29.

What do I miss here?

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847361/nsdateformatter-returning-wrong-year

Answer (score 2):

The primary cause of your issue is the incorrect use of `YYYY` in the `dateFormat`. You need to be using `yyyy` for the year. `YYYY` is similar but it typically gives the wrong results during the last half of the last week of the year (like now).

See [Date Field Symbol Table](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) and see the difference between y and Y.

As for why the SwiftUI code in the simulator gives a different result than the Swift code in a Playground, I suspect it has to do with the default locale and/or calendar being used by the two. Either way, correctly using `yyyy` for the year will give you the correct result in both places.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @HangarRash the YYYY DateFormat is causing this.

Use yyyy instead of YYYY. The latter is the date formatter token for the year in the week of year calendar.

Comment: Please note that I removed my comments and posted a full answer before you posted this answer.